# Display a Google Form, newly created with Apps Script code, with code, to the user

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-apps, google-forms

Essentially, I want a user to be able to click on a menu item, and a form will open in the style of a quiz. The program will return the responses and check them with the correct answers, and return the results of the quiz. The problem is, the form is created but I can't find a way to access it. Here is the code that creates the form:

```js
var quizQuestions = ["question1", "q2", "q2"];
  var quizChoices = [["choice1", "c2", "c3", "c4"], ["c1", "c2", "c3", "c4"], ["c1", "c2", "c3", "c4"]];
  var quizAnswers = ["answer1", "a2", "a3"];
  var responses = [];
  var form = FormApp.create('Quiz');
  for(i=0; i<quizQuestions.length; i++) {
    form.addMultipleChoiceItem()
      .setTitle(quizQuestions[i])
      .setChoiceValues(quizChoices[i])
      .showOtherOption(true);
    }
```

I have tried using the FormApp.openById("id") method, but I cannot get the form itself to display to the user. I am working with Google Docs, not Spreadsheets, so it is difficult to find any documentation.

Comment: It's not possible to display the form in the browser from Apps Script (Server side code).  You need to have either an HTML sidebar or dialog box, that then calls Apps Script code with `google.script.run.myFunction()`.  Then gets a return value of what the new form URL is, then use `window.open('https://websitename.abc', '_blank');` to open the form in a new window.  It's a multi-step process.  There is no built-in way to do what you want in one step.